# Webscraping all hidden/nested options of a webform as a table using R

Tags: javascript, r, web-scraping, dplyr, rvest

I'm trying to scrape all form options/combinations from a url. However, it is designed in a hierarchical search format such that the next 3 layers of options wont show until you select an option from the first layer (State).  I have tried looking at codes here but can't find one that handles nested options with strings. Here is my sample code so far:

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr) 

url <- "https://inecnigeria.org/elections/polling-units"
pgsession <- session(url)
pgform1 <- html_form(pgsession)[[2]]
pgform2 <- html_form(pgsession)[[3]]

pgform1
<form> 'pollForm' (GET )
 <field> (select) states: 
 <field> (select) : 
 <field> (select) : 
 <field> (button) : Click to Search

 pgform2
<form> 'form1' (GET )
 <field> (select) states: 
 <field> (select) : 
 <field> (select) : 
 <field> (button) : Click to Search

#Extract all values for states (the first level of options)
ST1 <- pgform1[['fields']][['states']][['options']]
ST2 <- names(ST1)

head(ST2)
[1] "Choose State" "ABIA"         "ADAMAWA"      "AKWA IBOM"    "ANAMBRA"      "BAUCHI"  

pgform1[['fields']][[2]][['options']]
 named character(0)
```

Only the states show initially so I'm not able to fill in options for the next levels. The next level which is LGA (I dont know what it is titled as in the html script) only shows after you have selected a state and the next level which is Ward (I don't know what it is titled as in the html script) only shows when you have selected an LGA. The Polling units will then be listed after these selection. How do I scrape all the possible combinations from the hierarchy of options available? I hope to have a table that shows all combinations of the State, LGA, Ward, Polling Unit ID, Polling Unit Name and Remark.

EDIT:
I tried this and got a new error

```
 pgform2 <- set_values(pgform2, states = "Abia")
 result <- rvest::submit_form(session, pgform2, submit = "Click to Search" , httr::add_headers('x-requested-with' = 'XMLHttpRequest'))
```

This produced the error below:

```
Error in `submission_build()`:
! `form` doesn't contain a `action` attribute
```

UPDATE: The code by @Emmanuel works well but the list items don't have names. Is it possible to have list names in this format: State-LGA-Ward instead of [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsLdY.png)][[4]][[10]] as shown in the example below? Is there a time-efficient way to scrape knowing that the webpage is slow and unstable? It will make it easier to read the results and know where the polling units are located with list headers.

[image: Screen grab showing one of the sub lists]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider something like this :

```
library(stringr)
library(RSelenium)

rd <- rsDriver(chromever = "105.0.5195.52", browser = "chrome", port = 4480L) 
remDr <- rd$client
remDr$open()
url <- "https://inecnigeria.org/elections/polling-units/"
remDr$navigate(url)

Sys.sleep(15)

########################################
#### Get all the values of the form ####
########################################
web_Obj_State_Poll <- remDr$findElement("id", "statePoll")
html_Content_State_Poll <- web_Obj_State_Poll$getPageSource()[[1]]
options_State_Poll <- stringr::str_extract_all(html_Content_State_Poll, "<option value[^<]*\\d{1,2}[^<]*</option>")[[1]]
options_State_Poll <- stringr::str_replace_all(options_State_Poll, "(<option[^<]*>)(([:alpha:]|[:space:])*)(</option>)", "\\2")
web_Obj_State_Poll$sendKeysToElement(list(options_State_Poll[1]))

Sys.sleep(15)

web_Obj_LGA_Poll <- remDr$findElement("id", "lgaPoll")
web_Obj_LGA_Poll$sendKeysToElement(list("IVO"))
html_Content_LGA_Poll <- remDr$executeScript("return arguments[0].innerHTML", list(web_Obj_LGA_Poll))[[1]]
options_LGA_Poll <- stringr::str_extract_all(html_Content_LGA_Poll, "<option value[^<]*\\d{1,2}[^<]*</option>")[[1]]
options_LGA_Poll <- stringr::str_replace_all(options_LGA_Poll, "(<option[^<]*>)(([:alpha:]|[:space:]|-)*)(</option>)", "\\2")
web_Obj_LGA_Poll$sendKeysToElement(list(options_LGA_Poll[1]))

Sys.sleep(15)

web_Obj_Ward_Poll <- remDr$findElement("id", "wardPoll")
web_Obj_Ward_Poll$sendKeysToElement(list("AUCHI"))
html_Content_Ward_Poll <- remDr$executeScript("return arguments[0].innerHTML", list(web_Obj_Ward_Poll))[[1]]
options_Ward_Poll <- stringr::str_extract_all(html_Content_Ward_Poll, "<option value[^<]*\\d{1,2}[^<]*</option>")[[1]]
options_Ward_Poll <- stringr::str_replace_all(options_Ward_Poll, "(<option[^<]*>)(([:alpha:]|[:space:]|-)*)(</option>)", "\\2")
web_Obj_Ward_Poll$sendKeysToElement(list(options_Ward_Poll[1]))

Sys.sleep(15)

##############################################
#### Loop over all the values of the form ####
##############################################

list_Table_Form <- list()
nb_State_Poll <- length(options_State_Poll)
nb_Lga_Poll <- length(options_LGA_Poll)
nb_Ward_Poll <- length(options_Ward_Poll)

for(l1 in 1 : nb_State_Poll)
{
  list_Table_Form[[l1]] <- list()
  
  for(l2 in 1 : nb_Lga_Poll)
  {
    list_Table_Form[[l1]][[l2]] <- list()
    
    for(l3 in 1 : nb_Ward_Poll)
    {
      url <- "https://inecnigeria.org/elections/polling-units/"
      remDr$navigate(url)
      
      message_Print <- paste0("l1 : ", l1, " l2 : ", l2, " l3 : ", l3)
      print(message_Print)
      
      Sys.sleep(35)
      
      web_Obj_State_Poll <- remDr$findElement("id", "statePoll")
      web_Obj_State_Poll$sendKeysToElement(list(options_State_Poll[l1]))
      
      Sys.sleep(35)
      
      web_Obj_LGA_Poll <- remDr$findElement("id", "lgaPoll")
      web_Obj_LGA_Poll$sendKeysToElement(list(options_LGA_Poll[l2]))
      
      Sys.sleep(35)
      
      web_Obj_LGA_Poll <- remDr$findElement("id", "wardPoll")
      web_Obj_LGA_Poll$sendKeysToElement(list(options_Ward_Poll[l3]))
      
      Sys.sleep(35)
      
      web_Obj_SearchPoll <- remDr$findElement("id", "SearchPoll")
      web_Obj_SearchPoll$clickElement()
      
      Sys.sleep(35)
      
      web_Obj_Result <- remDr$findElement("id", "result")
      list_Table_Form[[l1]][[l2]][[l3]] <- strsplit(web_Obj_Result$getElementText()[[1]], "\n")[[1]]
      
      print(list_Table_Form[[l1]][[l2]][[l3]])
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I just ran it and this error popped up: Selenium message:no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#statePoll"}
  (Session info: chrome=106.0.5249.61)
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html

Comment: Error contd:       Error:   Summary: NoSuchElement
   Detail: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.
   class: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException
  Further Details: run errorDetails method

Comment: The webpage is very slow. You have to give time to the web page to load. Maybe you can increase the waiting delay (e. g. Sys.sleep(120) or Sys.sleep(180)). If the page is not loaded, Selenium will not find the elements in the web page.

Comment: Okay. Let me increase that and try again.

Comment: This morning, I did some tests and this website was extremely slow. It takes a lot of time to load.

Comment: Hi @Emmanuel, can you share a screen grab or the first 6 lines of what the table from the second method looks like on your end please?

Comment: Hi, I added a screen shot of the results of the code. The algorithm is working well. I changed the delays to 35 seconds. This website is not always stable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248491/discussion-between-joke-o-and-emmanuel-hamel).

Comment: Yes, no problem, you can communicate with me in the chat

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to fill the form and get the table with the following code :

```
library(stringr)
library(RSelenium)

rd <- rsDriver(chromever = "105.0.5195.52", browser = "chrome", port = 4449L) 
remDr <- rd$client
remDr$open()
url <- "https://inecnigeria.org/elections/polling-units/"
remDr$navigate(url)

Sys.sleep(1)

web_Obj_State_Poll <- remDr$findElement("id", "statePoll")
web_Obj_State_Poll$sendKeysToElement(list("EDO"))

Sys.sleep(1)

web_Obj_LGA_Poll <- remDr$findElement("id", "lgaPoll")
web_Obj_LGA_Poll$sendKeysToElement(list("IVO"))

Sys.sleep(1)

web_Obj_Ward_Poll <- remDr$findElement("id", "wardPoll")
web_Obj_Ward_Poll$sendKeysToElement(list("AUCHI"))

Sys.sleep(1)

web_Obj_SearchPoll <- remDr$findElement("id", "SearchPoll")
web_Obj_SearchPoll$clickElement()

web_Obj_Result <- remDr$findElement("id", "result")
strsplit(web_Obj_Result$getElementText()[[1]], "\n")[[1]]

[1] "Polling Unit ID Polling Unit Name Remark"            "001 IGUEBEN - AFUDA P/S/ I EXISTING PU"             
 [3] "002 IGUEBEN - AFUDA P/S/ II EXISTING PU"             "003 IGUEBEN - AFUDA P/S/ III EXISTING PU"           
 [5] "004 IGUEBEN - IDUMUOKA P/S/ EXISTING PU"             "005 OPEN SPACE BY AFUDA HEALTH CENTER NEW PU"       
 [7] "006 EGBESAN PRY SCH NEW PU"                          "007 AFUDA COMMUNITY HALL NEW PU"                    
 [9] "008 OPEN SPACE BY IDUMONKA PRY HEALTH CENTER NEW PU" "009 IDUMONKA COMMUNITY HALL NEW PU"
```

Comment: Thanks @Emmanuel. THis is very useful. Is there a way to rewrite the code so that it could be in a  "for i in " loop  or as a function that goes over each State, LGA and Ward combination?